# Is it possible to draw one way road direction arrows using CSS of GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, css, geoserver-css-module

Is it possible to draw one way road direction arrows using CSS of GeoServer?

I want to get the same result as shown below (see img-1).

(UPDATE)
So far, I've added arrow sign as label in separate layer and this is my result (see img-2). Arrows appear not everywhere, they are missing on "Guramishvili st" for instance.

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

Comment: what have you tried so far? what went wrong? - and yes you can do it.

Comment: I tried to use marks (symbol(arrow)) but failed, now I am thinking to place arrows as labels. But I'll appreciate any help if someone can help me.